# Update Statement updates all rows in table unexpectedly

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to overwrite the primary key(`draft_id`) in a table, with the primary key(`ro_id`) from another table. I only want to do this for a small number of the total rows, 56 out of a total of 24k.

I join the tables using a separate row in both tables, `group_id`. I also have an additional where clause to ensure I only update the desired rows. My query is below:

```sql
update data.foo
set draft_id = ro.ro_id
from data.foo r
         inner join data.bar as ro on r.group_id = ro.group_id
where r.draft_id in
      ('d49aaa45-2dd0-45aa-9e72-131b790fc75c', ...);
```

The problem is this query updates every single row, instead of the 56 expected:

```sql
UPDATE 24589
```

However, when I run this query, I get a count of 56:

```sql
select count(r.draft_id)
from data.foo r
         inner join data.bar as ro on r.group_id = ro.group_id
where r.draft_id in
      ('d49aaa45-2dd0-45aa-9e72-131b790fc75c', ...);
```

I abbreviated the list of keys used in the where clause, but there are 56, and I'm sure they are correct.

How can the update statement update more rows than there are keys given in the where clause?

For clarity, here is the SQL used to create the `data.bar` table, `data.foo` has two identical columns amongst others.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data.bar
(
    draft_id UUID NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT bar_pkey PRIMARY KEY,
    group_id       TEXT
);
```

I'm using the following versions:

psql (12.16, server 13.11 (Ubuntu 13.11-1.pgdg22.04+1))

Comment: I see someone voted to close the question. I'd love to hear any feedback on how I could have written it better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to add a `WHERE` condition that joins `foo` with the `FROM` clause. As a consequence, all rows are updated.

Your key mistake is that the statement uses `foo` twice: once in the `UPDATE` clause, and once in the `FROM` clause (alias `r`). Your statement joins three tables:

- `foo`
- `foo`, aliased as `r`
- `bar`, aliased as `ro`

And since there is no `WHERE` condition that joins `foo` with `r` or `ro`, you end up with a *cross join* that contains all rows from `foo`.

But really, you only want to join two tables: `foo` and `bar`. So omit the second, erroneous reference to `foo`

```
UPDATE data.foo
SET draft_id = ro.ro_id
FROM data.bar
WHERE foo.group_id = bar.group_id
  AND foo.draft_id IN ('d49aaa45-2dd0-45aa-9e72-131b790fc75c', ...);
```

Comment: Well, there is a where clause, it's just after the inner join line. If I move the where clause up between the `FROM` clause and the `INNER JOIN` clause, I get a syntax error. Can you give me an example of the query you mean?

Comment: I forgot to add I'll gladly mark your answer as accepted if you can share some working code. I don't quite follow what you mean by your answer right now.

Comment: I tried to explain it in more detail.

Comment: Ah yes this makes sense now. I think this is counter-intuitive, since I'd expect the where clause to filter down the cross-joined table in all cases. However, your query does work as expected, thanks for the very clear and helpful explanation.